# Adding border on form error causing change of input size

Tags: css

I am using the following simple jquery to add the class .error to an input element:

```
$(this).addClass("error");
```

The error class looks like this:

```
.error{
    border-color: red !important;
    border-style: solid !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

my input style:

```
.fatform {
    width:125px; 
    height:21px;  
    text-align:left; 
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); 
    border:none; 
    padding:10px; 
}

.checkout_float_left {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="checkout_float_left">
<input type="text" name="email" value="email@email.com" style="width:290px;" class="fatform error" title="E-Mail">  
</div>

<div class="checkout_float_left">               
<input type="text" name="phone" value="5144291849" style="width:290px;" class="fatform error" title="Phone Number">             
</div>
```

When the error class is activated the border shows properly but the input shrinks in size. If I don't use border-box sizing then when the border is shown it pushes the elements around because it changes the size of them to be larger.

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Can you add your html and enough code so we can replicate this error

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Added html

Comment: You can just comment out or remove the `height: 21px;`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding min-width to your css for input elements as it will fix sizes of input control.

Let me know if it will work for you

Comment: Adding min-width:125px; to the fatform class had no effect unfortunately.